# Background color for MenuItem not changed on MouseOver

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have a Menu with three items and I'm trying to change the background color when the mouse hovers over any of the items.  I've tried the IsMouseOver & IsHighlighted trigger property and neither works.

In my App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuItemStyle" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>          
    </Style>
```

In my Main.xaml:

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="975
          " FontFamily="Tempus Sans ITC" FontSize="16"  >
        <Menu.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFC8C8C8" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Menu.Background>
        <Menu.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFFFB"/>
        </Menu.Foreground>
        <MenuItem Header="New" Click="MenuNew_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="15,4,8,3" Width="60">
            <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    Add new Park
                </ToolTip>
            </MenuItem.ToolTip>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Search" Width="65" Padding="12,4,8,3"  >
            <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip> Select search option</ToolTip>
            </MenuItem.ToolTip>
            <MenuItem Header="Name" Background="Black" FontSize="14" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" />
            <MenuItem Header="ID" Background="Black" FontSize="14"/>
            <MenuItem Header="OwnerName" Background="Black" FontSize="14"/>
        </MenuItem>          
    </Menu>
```

Comment: What specific behavior do you want?  I tried out your code minus the unnecessary menu styling, and it changed color on mouseover.  In my test, it highlighted the whole menu, not just the single item.

Comment: Maybe try a different color on your trigger? It's black originally and you set it to black if mouse is over... no difference.

Comment: As it is now the background is black and text is white.  you select 'Search' the three items display in the drop down with black background.  But when the mouse is hovered over any of them the background is a light blue.  So with white text they are very  hard to read.

Comment: I had to make an update to the code above.  Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" is used in the first menuitem(after tooltip) to see if it will work for the remaining menuitems.

Answer (score 1):

The default `ControlTemplate` for `MenuItem` (as extracted by [Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/2091)) doesn't set the `MenuItem.Background` property on mouse over, it sets an element in the template directly. Unfortunately, this means that you won't be able to just change the highlight color, but you'll have to recreate the entire `ControlTemplate`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) has an example of how to do this (this one is from .NET 3.5 but should work for 4.0 or 4.5).

One other caveat in your code: since you're setting the `Background` directly on the `MenuItem`s, your `Style`'s `Trigger` would not work anyway. Because of [`DependencyProperty` value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), the local value you set on the items can not be overridden by a `Style` `Trigger`.

Comment: Thanks much for the advice and the links.  Looking forward to checking out that 'show me the template' program.