# Trigger not working on MenuItem Style in Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I have the following in a Resource dictionary. The style is working but the trigger is not. Please help.

```
 <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF181818" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13.333" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedBackgroundBrush}" />

         </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>


</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Background of the MenuItem is set by a Parent Template Trigger and by the rules of [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the value in the Template will be in force.

[Related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194967/background-color-for-menuitem-not-changed-on-mouseover): you have to override the control template of the `MenuItem`.

Comment: I'm new to WPF. Can You give an example of how to do that?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx) is a description. Basically you have to add a `<Setter Property="Template"><Setter.Value><ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}"><!-- Here comes the template --></ControlTemplate></Setter.Value></Setter>` to your Style there.

I would use the default ControlTemplate of the MenuItem as a base.
[Default Template related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548319/where-can-i-find-the-default-wpf-control-templates)

I can't find the templates on MSDN..

Comment: <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedBackgroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>      --- this make the menu vanish.